# Highcharts in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: highcharts, google-apps-script

Has anyone gotten Highcharts working within Google Apps Scripts.
http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/download.jsp

I know that you can do in GWT via:
http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/quickstart.jsp

Is there anyone aware of how to apply this to Google Apps Scripts environment?

Comment: Yes. Posted the answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893840/highcharts-highstock-supported-in-google-sites/35214405#35214405

Answer (score 0):

If you're using HtmlService to publish your web app, you can certainly add the Highcharts javascript file to your page with `<script>` tags, but be warned that Google Caja sanitizes your HTML code before it displays it to the user. What does this mean? Well, since the highcharts js file is pretty big, it will take a while (in the realm of several seconds) to sanitize it.

You're probably better off using the Apps Script [Charts service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_charts).