# Highcharts/Highstock supported in Google Sites?

Tags: google-apps-script, highcharts, google-sites

Is it possible to embed Highcharts scripts in Google sites?

I've tried inserting an HTML box and also throwing everything in an HTML file and calling it via a Google Apps script. So far, both methods just give me all the text from the graph (title, axis labels, etc.), but no graph. I know embedding JS in a Google site is kind of tricky, but can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

No. SVG (which Highcharts uses) is not supported within Caja (which an HTML Box and Apps Script use to sanitize and ensure safe code).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as of Jan 2016 (at least), I can easily use a *highcharts* library in GAS.

A dynamically updating graph using *highcharts* library within GAS environment can be found here: [GAS-highcharts](https://github.com/electronicsguy/MereScripts/tree/master/Google-Apps/Highcharts)

A Working example is here: [working-highcharts-GAS](http://bit.ly/1SMJ4st)

It is based on this JSFiddle: jsfiddle (dot) net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/